# Pages load without Images through ajax request in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I have converted HTML pages to ASP.NET CORE 2.1 MVC App and I am loading pages through ajax request. When the ajax request is made, the pages do load but without Images. Please have a look at my code and help me solve this issue.

Best Regards

I have created a shared layout (master layout) with name _PublicLayout.cshtml.
In the body tag, I am rendering pages. And in the end of the body tag, I have code JQuery AJAX function - which request other pages. The pages are successfully loaded but without images.

```
@{
    Layout= "_Layout.cshtml";
}
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

  <main id="content" role="main">
@RenderBody()
@await Html.PartialAsync("_Footer")
  </main>



<script>
var BASE_URL = "https://localhost:5001"; 

  $('.link').click(function(){
    var href= $(this).attr('href');
    var url = BASE_URL+href;

$.get(url,function(page){
  $('#content').load(page); 
  $(document).scrollTop();
  $('#content').css('top', screenTop);
});

    return false;
  });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the page that needs to be loaded with Images through AJAX Request.

```
@{
    Layout = "_PublicLayout";
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}

    <!-- Item -->
        <div class="cbp-item">
          <div class="cbp-caption">
            <a class="cbp-lightbox u-media-viewer" href="/img/1920x1920/img1.jpg" data-title="Front in frames - image #01">
              <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="/img/500x805/img1.jpg" alt="Image Description">
              <span class="u-media-viewer__container">
                <span class="u-media-viewer__icon">
                  <span class="fas fa-plus u-media-viewer__icon-inner"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item -->

        <!-- Item -->
        <div class="cbp-item">
          <div class="cbp-caption">
            <a class="cbp-lightbox u-media-viewer" href="/img/1920x1080/img27.jpg" data-title="Front in frames - image #02">
              <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="/img/380x227/img1.jpg" alt="Image Description">
              <span class="u-media-viewer__container">
                <span class="u-media-viewer__icon">
                  <span class="fas fa-plus u-media-viewer__icon-inner"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item -->

        <!-- Item -->
        <div class="cbp-item">
          <div class="cbp-caption">
            <a class="cbp-lightbox u-media-viewer" href="/img/1920x1920/img16.jpg" data-title="Front in frames - image #03">
              <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="/img/380x360/img23.jpg" alt="Image Description">
              <span class="u-media-viewer__container">
                <span class="u-media-viewer__icon">
                  <span class="fas fa-plus u-media-viewer__icon-inner"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item -->

        <!-- Item -->
        <div class="cbp-item">
          <div class="cbp-caption">
            <a class="cbp-lightbox u-media-viewer" href="/img/1920x1080/img4.jpg" data-title="Front in frames - image #04">
              <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="/img/380x227/img2.jpg" alt="Image Description">
              <span class="u-media-viewer__container">
                <span class="u-media-viewer__icon">
                  <span class="fas fa-plus u-media-viewer__icon-inner"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item -->

        <!-- Item -->
        <div class="cbp-item">
          <div class="cbp-caption">
            <a class="cbp-lightbox u-media-viewer" href="/img/1920x1080/img25.jpg" data-title="Front in frames - image #05">
              <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="/img/380x360/img24.jpg" alt="Image Description">
              <span class="u-media-viewer__container">
                <span class="u-media-viewer__icon">
                  <span class="fas fa-plus u-media-viewer__icon-inner"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item -->

        <!-- Item -->
        <div class="cbp-item">
          <div class="cbp-caption">
            <a class="cbp-lightbox u-media-viewer" href="/img/1920x1080/img21.jpg" data-title="Front in frames - image #06">
              <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="/img/380x360/img22.jpg" alt="Image Description">
              <span class="u-media-viewer__container">
                <span class="u-media-viewer__icon">
                  <span class="fas fa-plus u-media-viewer__icon-inner"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item -->

        <!-- Item -->
        <div class="cbp-item">
          <div class="cbp-caption">
            <a class="cbp-lightbox u-media-viewer" href="/img/1920x1080/img26.jpg" data-title="Front in frames - image #07">
              <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="/img/380x227/img3.jpg" alt="Image Description">
              <span class="u-media-viewer__container">
                <span class="u-media-viewer__icon">
                  <span class="fas fa-plus u-media-viewer__icon-inner"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item -->
      </div>
      <!-- End Content -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Frames Section -->
```

**NOTE:** 

 The page with images loads fine through direct requests. But the problem is occuring in requests.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue through github?